# Can't detect wireless access points on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, wifi, kali-linux, access-point

So I have Kali Linux installed on my Lenovo g500 laptop. Wired connections work just fine but I cannot connect to wireless access points or detect them.
I am literally out of ideas, so here is the information that might help you help me : 
-When I start up the computer(Kali Linux is my only OS and its not from a live CD or anything like that) wireless isn't even turned on, and it doesn't even detect the card. Here is the output of `iwconfig` and `ifconfig` after booting:

```
# iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

# ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:1a:06:99:1e:2c  
          inet addr:***.***.*.***  Bcast:***.***.*.*** Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: ****::****:***:****:****/** Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:769 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:750 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:425266 (415.2 KiB)  TX bytes:106759 (104.2 KiB)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:***.*.*.*  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:960 (960.0 B)  TX bytes:960 (960.0 B)
```

I have been solving this by doing this:

```
compat-wireless-2010-06-26-p# make unload
/sbin/modprobe: invalid option -- 'l'
/sbin/modprobe: invalid option -- 'l'
Stoping bluetooth service..
[ ok ] Stopping bluetooth: rfcomm /usr/sbin/bluetoothd.
[FAIL] bluetooth is not running ... failed!
Unloading rfcomm...
compat-wireless-2010-06-26-p# make load
/sbin/modprobe: invalid option -- 'l'
/sbin/modprobe: invalid option -- 'l'
Stoping bluetooth service..
[ ok ] Stopping bluetooth: rfcomm /usr/sbin/bluetoothd.
[FAIL] bluetooth is not running ... failed!
Unloading rfcomm...
/sbin/modprobe: invalid option -- 'l'
/sbin/modprobe: invalid option -- 'l'
Loading ipw2100...
Loading ipw2200...
Loading libertas_cs...
Loading usb8xxx...
Loading p54pci...
Loading p54usb...
Loading adm8211...
Loading zd1211rw...
Loading rtl8180...
FATAL: Module rtl8180 not found.
Loading rtl8187...
Loading p54pci...
Loading p54usb...
Loading iwl3945...
Loading iwlagn...
FATAL: Module iwlagn not found.
Loading ath...
Loading ar9170usb...
Loading rtl8180...
FATAL: Module rtl8180 not found.
Loading rtl8187...
Loading rt2400pci...
Loading rt2500pci...
Loading rt61pci...
Loading rt2500usb...
Loading rt73usb...
Loading rndis_wlan...
Loading at76_usb...
FATAL: Module at76_usb not found.
Loading mwl8k...
Loading mac80211_hwsim...
Loading at76c50x_usb...
Loading bluetooth...
Loading btusb...
Loading l2cap...
FATAL: Module l2cap not found.
Loading sco...
FATAL: Module sco not found.
Loading hidp...
Loading rfcomm...
Loading bnep...
./scripts/load.sh: line 21: athload: command not found
./scripts/load.sh: line 23: b43load: command not found
Starting bluetooth service..
[ ok ] Starting bluetooth: bluetoothd rfcomm.
[ ok ] bluetooth is running.
```

Now I see a lot of 'Fatal's in there and I don't know if that's ok or not.
Now the output of `ifconfig` and `iwconfig` is:

```
# iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan1     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

hwsim0    no wireless extensions.

    # ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:1a:06:99:1e:2c  
          inet addr:***.***.*.***  Bcast:***.***.*.*** Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: ****::****:***:***:****/** Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:960 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:933 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:466438 (455.5 KiB)  TX bytes:204104 (199.3 KiB)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:***.*.*.*  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1200 (1.1 KiB)  TX bytes:1200 (1.1 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:00:00:00:00:00  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:00:00:00:01:00  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Now on the right corner when I click on the network icon it shows :

```
 Wired Network
  Wired Connection 1
   disconnect ##this is a clickable button ... 
 Wireless Network (wlan0)
   disconnected ##unclickable button
 Wireless Network (wlan1)
   disconnected ##unclickable button
```

I have a wireless router that has worked on this laptop before from Windows 7 and from Linux Mint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a large number of posts about the `Broadcom BCM43142` having issues in kali, although i did dig up this bit:

```
add all Kali repositories to /etc/apt/sources.list:

deb http://http.kali.org/ /kali main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/ /wheezy main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main/debian-installer
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main/debian-installer
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free

install "broadcom-sta-dkms" package (ver 6.30.223.248-1)
```

the above is taken from [here](http://www.kalilinux.net/threads/how-to-make-broadcom-bcm43142-wireless-card-work-in-kali.814/). as an alternative, you can also add a usb wifi dongle - there's a pretty good list [here](http://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/01/08/recommended-usb-wireless-cards-kali-linux/). good luck!

Comment: I did what you told me, but i its the same thing, broadcom-sta-dkms package installed just fine, i restarted the laptop and nothing changed. Is it possible kali linux doesent support my wireless card at all?(and also thank you for responding, it means a lot to me :D )

Comment: that is totally possible... sorry. it might be worth investing in one of the usb wifi sticks. personally, i have 2 of the TP-LINK TL-WN722N and they're not bad. i'm sure there's better, but kali supports them with no additional fuss and they're less than 15$ on amazon, so it's not like you're breaking the bank for a fix. cheers!

Comment: Well thank you very much for the help, i will research a little on what  wifi stick i should get . Nice day to you sir :) !